Why the fullCalendar v5 did not refresh
Why the fullCalendar v5 did not refresh after any update or delete or add operations. if anyone know the reason, please help me to resolve this problem.
I try the below code to refresh the Calender.
And this is my code, to refresh the FullCalender. but it did not working.
`.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Event updated successfully!',
        }).then(() => {
        // Refresh the calendar after updating the event
           calendar.refetchEvents(); 
           });
    } else {
    console.error('Failed to update the event');
    throw new Error('Failed to update the event');
    }
 })`

